# How <sws:annotation-driven /> with marshaller works

Tags: java, spring-ws

When in my application context add this row where is this marshallers set ?

```
<sws:annotation-driven marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller" />
```

I thought that spring-ws use it for un/marshaling request response but I was wrong because it must be like

```
<bean id="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor">
    <constructor-arg ref="marshaller" />
</bean>
```

UPDATE:

```
sws:annotation
```

should be equivalent of

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping"/>
```

so what is equivalent of sws:annotation with marshaller

Answer (score 2):

Simple JAX-WS provider webservice implemetation, as we know this type implementation is required only when there is huge xml file data input, JAXB will be performance pain for huge xml data

as we know SEI webservices are easy to implement and maintain, but fails on xml data parsing for huge data in soap message.

using the Spring-ws with provider payload we can implement the JAX-WS provider web service

how the spring-ws works in provider base soap xml messages.

*xml configuration*

```
<sws:annotation-driven/>

<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="DataLoadService" portTypeName="publishMessage"
            locationUri="/soap/services" targetNamespace="http://www.informatica.com/wsdl/">
            <sws:xsd location="https://sample.application/publishMessage.xsd" />
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>
```

above configuration will read the xsd from the remote location and generate the wsdl file for the web service method expose. if required we can use application marshalling/un marshalling by configuring the classes.

*java implementation*

```
@Endpoint
public class DataLoadServiceEndPoint {

    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "publishMessageRequest", namespace = "http://www.informatica.com/wsdl/")
    @ResponsePayload
    public Element processRequest(@RequestPayload Element requestNode) {
    .....
    }
}
```

above endpoint will receive the xml element document i.e. payload data from the soapMessage.

history of spring-ws marshal/unmarshal

oxm namespace to define your marshaller:

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" >
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="...xml elements.."/>
</oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>

Or 
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="xx.aa.ws"/>
```

latest spring release after spring 2.x removed reference to GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter and PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping, replace both with "sws namespace"

```
<sws:annotation-driven  />

OR explicitly specify the marshaller/unmarshaller:

<sws:annotation-driven marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller"/>
```

i hope your aware of what is marshaller/unmarshaller and provider base web service with payload data from soap Message.

```
<sws:annotation-driven /> - for the default xsd/schema based payload i.e.


    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "SampleRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public Element processRequest(@RequestPayload Element requestNode)  throws Exception {
    
    }

<sws:annotation-driven marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller" />

When we want to use Objects as @PayloadRoot value not schema xml then we need to implement our own marshall/unmarshall adapters.

    i.e.
    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "SampleRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public SampleRequest processRequest(@RequestPayload SampleRequest sampleRequest) throws Exception {
    
    }
```

[for details](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/oxm.html#d0e26164)

Comment: I know how ws works. I just wanna know different between <sws:annotation-driven marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller" /> and <sws:annotation-driven />

Comment: sorry for late response but I still dont understand differences. I update my answer. I just want to know where are these marshallers used in spring-ws code (setter)